# two projects and one database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I have below scenario
Project A
 
Project B
Both have single database
Both have single admin panel
Both have different domain

Now I am having some problem regarding this:
1) How to keep uploaded images separate so that i can access images easily.
2) Do I have to keep same model files both sides.
3) how to deploy these app differently and access that image folder?

Thanks

Comment: How are your questions related to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the details you've given it seems like you want to have a single database but different images.

Best way to move forward for the above given approach would be to have a database hosted on cloud(single database hosted locally or on cloud) and then using that host details specified in the database.yml.

For saving images use

**Cloudinary**
(https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem)

or

**AWS S3**
(https://github.com/fog/fog)

for saving images on cloud with each image having a unique URL and saving the reference of the same in the database and using as per requirements in the 2 applications.